# Jenkins runs Failsafe Integration Tests despite of -DskipITs

Tags: jenkins, maven-failsafe-plugin

I got a maven multi module project and for one module im using Integration Tests against my **local database**. We use **Jenkins** and of course I don't want the ITs to run on Jenkins because of the required database. I found the solution to use **maven-failsafe** and the option "**-DskipITs**". Worked like a charm, i can commit ITs and don't have to worry about the Jenkins complaining about executing the ITs. But then I created a testsuite for all my ITs to run them all at one:

```
package mypackage;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    AccountManagerImportServiceIT.class,
    AccountManagerToClientImportServiceIT.class,
    ClientImportServiceIT.class,
    ContactPersonImportServiceIT.class,
    InvoiceImportServiceIT.class,
    MeteringPointImportServiceIT.class,
    MeteringPointToRoleImportServiceIT.class,
    RoleImportServiceIT.class,
    WhitelistImportServiceIT.class
})

public class TestSuiteIT {
}
```

Now it seems that Jenkins ignores failsafe for the TestSuite and tries to execute it, which of course makes the build unstable. I have no idea what to do to tell Jenkins to also ignore the TestSuite! The strange thing is: If I do a "mvn clean install -DskipITs" (the same command Jenkins executes) on my local system, it works. But Jenkins always tries to execute the TestSuite. :-(

Comment: Are you using surefire or failsafe plugin?

Comment: failsafe, as I have written in my question. It makes it possible to "seperate" unit-tests from integration-tests.

Comment: In your `pom.xml` have you made any configuration to your `fails-safe-plugin` to skip the tests?Something like this: 

`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`

Comment: I don't want to skip all tests, only the integration tests. And I don't want to skip them via default, but only with the maven parameter "-DskipITs" on the Jenkins-Build. As I have written before, without the Testsuite it works perfectly, but if Jenkins finds a Testsuite, it ignores this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<skipTests>false</skipTests>` to the `properties` section of your `pom.xml`.

Then in the `plugins` section find `maven-failsafe-plugin` and use the `skipTests` configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>x.xx</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

By default the tests will be enabled. If you want to skip the teststhen use `mvn install -DskipTests=true`

Comment: This will skip all Tests, but I just don't want the Jenkins to run the IntegrationTests. The UnitTests should still be executed!

Comment: You can exclude unit tests using regular expressions: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: I don't want to exclude unit tests. I want to exclude IntegrationTests, but ONLY ON JENKINS.